# IO Monad vs Reader Monad

Tags: scalaz, scala-cats, cats-effect, zio

I wonder is there any relation between IO Monad and the Reader monad ?

Can the Environment in the Reader monad be an effect ? If so, how does ZIO or Cats IO, scalaz-effects deal with Reader Monad principles ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment in a `Reader` is usually not an effect - it doesn't need to be.

To understand why, you first need to understand that the `Reader` monad is an abstraction over functions `A => B`, where `A` is some kind of environment.

In general, if you have an effect `F[A]`, you can always `map` the value using the `Reader`'s `apply` - function, right?

For `cats-effect`, a `Reader` is simply defined as a `Kleisli` (an abstraction over functions `A => F[B]`) with `F[_]` being defined as `type F[A] = A`. `Kleisli` provides everything you need in terms of composition, which is why `Reader`'s were defined to be a subset of `Kleisli`s. You can read more about it [here](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html).

For `ZIO`, things look a a little different.

Take a look at the definition: `ZIO[R, E, A]`. These three type parameters describe the environment (`R`), the error type (`E`) and the result type (`A`).

This means that `ZIO` is already a combination of the `IO` and `Reader` monads.
In `ZIO`, you can access the environment using the `access`- function.